# Dynamic Css Media Query

Tags: css, media-queries

```
@media (min-width: THIS-VALUE) {
.CLASS {
    Width: QUERY-WIDTH;
}
```

Is this Possible?
Please explain with example.
Thanks

Comment: If there is any other possible value then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an example of a css pre-processor. You can set variables in less that can be re-used throughout your css.

> Less is a CSS pre-processor, meaning that it extends the CSS language, adding features that allow **variables**, mixins, functions and many other techniques that allow you to make CSS that is more maintainable, themable and extendable.

Check out a couple of options:

http://lesscss.org/

Comment: Is it possible in CSS?

Comment: not that I know of, (although this is possibly coming) you can make use of these features when you write in the less syntax then compile it to css.

Comment: I know the less but i was just asking about css. So i will try in less. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible is CSS. you can use that in css pre-processors like Less, sass, SCSS, Stylus Etc.

in that case you can use % to set full size width.