# Can Media Query Using Dynamic Size on width?

Tags: html, css

I'm new when using media query, but I just found out when trying to develop a Desktop application (using electron but the CSS concept is still the same as normal web development) that there is a condition like this.

usually I'm using media screen like this (in this example I'm using 3 device as example: mobile, tablet, & desktop):

```
// default style for desktop
.my-default-css-code-is-here

// tablet
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
   .my-specific-css-code-for-tablet-is-here
}

// mobile
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   .my-specific-css-code-for-mobile-is-here
}
```

but my friend ask me like this:

> "For this desktop application we want to have a layout like this: `Normal Size (window-size): > 60%` and when has a tablet size than at least the style will change if window around `Tablet Size (window-size): <= 60% desktop resolution (Laptop or PC resolution such as HD, retina, etc. )` How can we achieve this?"

Since I'm usually using fixed size, I don't know if `@media screen` can achieve this. can someone help me about this problem? I'm quite confused myself about this. can I use Ratio like in [this article](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1) ? or can I just apply it like this?

```
// Desktop
@media screen and (min-width: 60% from A full Resolution) and (max-width: 100% from A full Resolution) {

}

// Tablet
@media screen and (max-width:  59% from A full Resolution) {

}
```

or

```
// default css
.my-code-is-here {}

// Tablet
@media screen and (max-width: 59% from A full Resolution) {
   .my-code-for-tablet-is-here {}
}
```

for more information, Let say if there is 2 type of laptop:

Laptop A :

`Real resolution = 1368px, The it means 59% from real is 807px`

Laptop B :

`Real resolution = 2560px, The it means 59% from real is 1510px`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29939039/8524381

Comment: @mohsenZare thankyou for the reference, but it quite a different problem, where in your reference we can achieve it using `:root` and add a varible, in my problem more like `how to make css differ the screen dynamically like using calc or just percentage based on device resolution`

Comment: Do you want to determine if the resolution has changed?

Comment: @MahmoudValizadeh thankyou for the response, if `determine` in here mean stating a fixed resolution such as `@media screen and (max-width: 2560px)` then "no", but if it can read current resolution such as percentage or the full resolution size without we stating the fixed size then "yes"

Answer (score 1):

if you want your media screen be dynamic. you can use npm package [postcss-media-variables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-media-variables)
this package allow you to use css variable in media query. you can set your css variable in javascript and use it in media query like :

```
:root {
  --min-width: 1000px;
}
@media (min-width: var(--min-width)) {}
```

you can change your css variable --min-width in javascript

Comment: thankyou for your answer, after I read the `postcss-media-variables` from several source, I think this is still not the solution I search, after read several article about it, this library help to translate the variable from root but it still can't read the dynamic resolution from the different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not entirely sure to understand what you are trying to achieve, I can explain quickly about vw (width of the viewport) and vh (height of the viewport). These two values are relative to the current displayed **viewport** only and for that reason, will change if you are displaying the website on a desktop screen (lets say 1920px by 1080px) (vw by vh) compared to displaying the website on a tablet (much less for vw and vh).

Said another way, they don't depend on the device itself, whether it's a laptop or a mobile phone, but only on the actual active viewport (viewport = the browser windows size). More info here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

From what I understand of your friend's request, you should/could still use fixed values for your media queries, customizing them to fit your website actual layout on each screen size.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, before I think exactly like your answer, but when he states that if for example there is 2 kind of laptop resolution such as `1366px` and `2560px` than the tablet view will has a fixed value and there will be a condition where a device will directly go to that resolution without ever achieving a desktop layout since his screen < 1366px`

Comment: OK, Im still a bit confused by the request, but concerning the "device width" or height, it has been deprecated in Media Queries Level 4 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) So I believe you can only test for the viewport as of now, so I think that no, you cannot read the % of the device's width in terms of vw or any other unit using CSS alone.

Comment: Thankyou for the reference, I'll try to look at it first